# If statement on 2 instances of object is not working for me

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-views

Am trying to create a user request from an existing model object but it wont work. Even the ajax on the html page keep reloading.

Here's my model

```
class Users_Balanc(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Amount = models.FloatField(max_length=4, default=0.0)
    Profit = models.FloatField(max_length=30, default=0.0)
    Bonus = models.FloatField(max_length=30, default=10.0)
    Referral_Bonus = models.FloatField(max_length=30, default=0.00)
    Deposit = models.FloatField(max_length=30, default=0.00)
    Withdrawals = models.FloatField(max_length=30, default=0.00)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Users_Balanc'
```

And my view

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def withdrawals(request):
    total = Users_Balanc.objects.all()
        #return render(request, 'dashboard/withdrawals.html', {'total': total})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Amount = request.POST['Amount']
        username = request.GET.get['username']
        total = Users_Balanc.objects.all()
            
        if (total.Amount <= Amount):
            New_Request = Request.objects.create(value=Amount, user=username)
            New_Request.save
            messages.info(request, 'Successful')
            return HttpResponse('Request sent sucessful')
            
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Insufficient funds')
    else:
        return render(request, 'dashboard/withdrawals.html', {'total': total})
```

Html form

```
<form id="post-form">
                                    {% csrf_token %}                              
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    
                                        <h5 class="text-light">Amount</h5>
                                        <input class="form-control text-light bg-dark" placeholder="TRX Amount" type="number" name="Amount" required>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="{{username}}"/>
                                    </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <h5 class="text-light">Enter withdrawal password</h5>
                                            <!--<input class="form-control text-light bg-dark" placeholder="Password" type="text" name="otpcode">-->
                                            <small class="text-light">If you forgot your password, you can contact admin</small>
                                        </div> 
                                                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="btn btn-danger" type='submit' value="Complete Request"/>
                                    </div>
```

**It returns an nothing at all after submit button is clicked**

For more clarification, am using ajax post request method on the html page to return the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that could be going wrong here:

First off - you are looking for for both a GET and a POST. try:

```
    Amount = request.POST['Amount']
    username = request.POST['username']
```

Second,

```
total = Users_Balanc.objects.all()
```

This can return multiple objects, so total.Amount doesn't mean anything - it won't add them for you. If a user only has one account, you might try

```
total = Users_Balanc.objects.get(user__username = username)
```

then total.Amount will work.

If a user can have multiple accounts (which is indicated by the foriegn key 'user') you might want to try something like

```
user_accounts= Users_Balanc.objects.filter(user__username = username).aggregate(total_amount = Sum('total'))
```

This will 1) filter all the Users_Balanc objects that belong to one user then 2) add all the 'total' fields of those objects to produce  user_accounts.total_amount so you can:

```
 if (user_accounts.total_amount <= Amount):
```

And this will work if the user has one or many accounts - though it doesn't check if there is enough money in a *single* account if the user has many accounts.

Comment: Input_Amount = request.POST['Input_Amount']
        username = request.POST['username']
        total = Users_Balanc.objects.get(user=request.user)
            
        if (total.Amount <= Input_Amount):
            New_Request = Request.objects.create(value=Input_Amount, user=username)
            New_Request.save
            messages.success(request, 'Successful')
            return redirect(request, 'dashboard/withdrawals.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Insufficient funds')

Comment: Have tried that, it didn't work. and have even change the method am using instead of ajax and its telling me (Cannot assign "''": "Request.user" must be a "User" instance)

Comment: IF the user is always going to be the request.user, you may not need to worry about the hidden username field, which could be confusing things.  In the code in the comment, you are using `user = username` which is not a type match and judging by the error the hidden field may be blank in your form. Use `user__username = username` if you want to use the hidden field, or  `user = request.user` if it's always going to be the user making the request.

Comment: Thanks SamSparx have fix it though. The hidden username was to make the work easier but Lmao it wasn't as easy as i thought. Thanks man